# Kendo Grid showing all remaining items on second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a web page I inherited that has a kendo grid on it displaying some data.  The grid is set up with paging enabled client side with different page sizes available.  Semi-Sanitized code below:

```
self.loadGrid = function (someId, anotherId, pager) {
    var pageSizeActive = 20;
    var pageNumberActive = 1;

    var grid = $("#MyItemGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    if (grid) {
        //apply pager values
        var pagerValue = $('.k-pager-sizes').find('.k-input').html();
        if (pagerValue) {
            //persist selecter page size
            pageSizeActive = pagerValue;
        }
        //selected page number
        if (pager) {
            //edit and delete stay on same page number
            pageNumberActive = grid.dataSource.page();
        }
    }

    var columnList = null;
    gridDataSource = {
        transport: {
            read: function (options) {
                var list = new lookupList(someId, anotherId);
                list.get(options.success, options.error);
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "ItemId",
                fields: {
                    ItemId: { typ: "int", editable: false, nullable: true },
                    Author: { type: "string", validation: { required: false } }
                }
            }
        },
        page: pageNumberActive,
        pageSize: pageSizeActive,
        serverPaging: false,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        change: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
    };

    columnList = [
        {
            field: "check_item", title: "<input type='checkbox' id='chkItemsSelectAll' onclick='SelectItemAll();'/>",
            template: "<input type='checkbox' id='noteChk' onclick='chkOrUnchkCompleteItem(this)'/>",
            width: '30px', sortable: false, filterable: false
        },
        {
            field: "critical_item", title: " ",
                template: "<a href='javascript:;' onclick='ChangeItemStatus(#=MainId()#,#=ItemId()#);'><span class='" + ViewModel.itemImageCritical() + " k-grid-cell-critical-off' aria-hidden='true'><span></a>",
            width: '24px', height: '20px', sortable: false, filterable: false
        },
        { field: "ItemDate()", title: "Date/Time", type: "date", format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mmsstt}", width: "160px", template: '#=StyleDateTime(ItemDate())#', sortable: false, filterable: false },
        {
            field: "manual_item", title: " ",
            template: "<span class='" + ViewModel.itemImageManual() + " k-grid-cell-manual-off' aria-hidden='true' title='date was manually entered'><span>",
            width: '24px', height: '20px', sortable: false, filterable: false
        },
        { field: "Author", title: "Author", width: "200px", sortable: false, filterable: false },
        {
            field: "subject_item", title: "Item",
            template: "<span>" + '#if(Subject() == null) {##}else{# #=Subject()#' + '<br/>' + ' # }#' + "#=ItemView()#" + "<span>",
            width: '100%', sortable: false, filterable: false
        },
        {
            command: [
                {
                    name: "Edit",
                    click: function (e) {
                        var record = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                        var myItem = record;
                        _item = myItem;
                        if (_item != null) {
                            if (_item.canComplete()) {
                                $('#btnComplete').prop('disabled', false);
                            }
                            else {
                                $('#btnComplete').prop('disabled', true);
                            }
                        }

                        kendo.bind($("#WindowCreateItem"), myItem);

                        $('#btnDelete').prop('disabled', false);
                        var win = $("#WindowCreateEditItem").data("kendoWindow");
                        win.center();
                        win.open();

                        $("#divErrItem").hide();
                        $("#NewItemName").removeClass('sp-error');
                    }
                }
            ],
            title: "&nbsp;",
            width: "100px"
        }
    ];

    if (grid != null) {
        grid.destroy();
        grid.wrapper.empty();
    }

    $("#MyItemGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: gridDataSource,
        change: function (e) {
            syncCheckBoxes();
        },
        //height: 455,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        selectable: "multiple, row",
        filterable: true,
        pageable: {
            pageSizes: [20, 60, 100]
        },
        editable: false,
        dataBound: function (e) {
            itemApplyStyling(e);
            CheckCanEditItem(e);
        },
        columns: columnList
    });
};
```

The issue I am having is that when I initially load the data (data is loaded via an ajax call separately), the first page of 20 (the initial page size) shows correctly.  If I put a breakpoint in the change function shown above that only has a log in it (not the second change function), I will see that "e" when viewing page 1 is 20 records in length.  When i click on page 2 however, "e" is the remaining records in length.  For example, if the data pulled from the ajax call is 209 records in length, page 1 has 20 records, page 2 has 189.  The pagination boxes at the bottom though would still show 11 pages, each one (except the last for some reason) showing 189 records.  The last shows 9.

Did the original author misconfigure something?  I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Which change function? The data source change function or the grid change function?

Comment: Try adding the `pageSize: pageNumberActive` property under the `pageable: { }` settings of the grid. Does that make a difference?

Comment: updated the post clarifying the change function.  Tried the pageSize: pageSizeActive (pageNumberActive just made the pages one item long).  Didn't help.  I've decided to try moving the paging server side using the properties passed into the web api call for now.

Comment: Oops, yea, I meant `pageSizeActive`. Would you be able to provide a jsBin or jsFiddle example of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but, I just have a similar problem.
If you note in your code, you have this in your gridDataSource:

```
serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true,
```

...and...it affect the pagination too, so it goes to the server.
You should use this:

```
serverFiltering: false,
        serverSorting: false,
```

It solve my problem.
You can play with this example:
http://dojo.telerik.com/@Kiril/EFAb